# Libgdx jump and collision method not working everytime I hit Space

Tags: java, libgdx

So, I am writing a game in Libgdx. But I have a problem. I use rectangle overlapping to detect collisions. When I jump(hit space), it happens properly the first time, but following it, the state constantly changes between overlapping and not overlapping, and because of that I cannot always jump, I jump only when the sprite is in not overlapping state.
What do I do?

This is my update method, that controls the jumping.
(posY is the variable being used to specify the y-coordinate of the sprite)

```
public void update(float dt) {
        bottom = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
        y = posY;

        velocityY -= 70 * dt;
        y += velocityY;

        if(!bottom.overlaps(Main.ground) && isJumping) {
            posY = y;
            System.out.println("Overlapping");
        }
        else {
            velocityY = 0;
            posY = 10;
            System.out.println("Not Overlapping");
        }
    }
```

This is the output after jumping the first time

```
Not Overlapping
Overlapping
Not Overlapping
Overlapping
Not Overlapping
Overlapping
Not Overlapping
Overlapping
Not Overlapping
Overlapping
Not Overlapping
Overlapping
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Why you don't use Box2d?

Comment: I would say that when you set posY to 10 your character is moved to positions where it overlaps ground. Try setting different value (a bit higher or a bit lower).